# how can i get the working path of my image in codeigniter when uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I have a code in codeigniter which i will store the path of my image in my database. It works fine in inserting but the path is not correct.

My folder name of my upload images are stored in upimages.
The upimages is located in outside of application folder in codeigniter where i created assets/upimages. Here is my path code in inserting to database:

```
          $data = $this->upload->data();

           $image_path = $data['full_path'];
           //var_dump($image_path);
           $userid = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['user_id']);
           $imagedb = $this->prof_model->user_img($image_path,$userid);
             if(file_exists($image_path)) {
                $status = "success";
                $msg = "File successfully uploaded";

           }
```

my image_path is the full path of my image but it outputs none if i call it again and here is the output of the full_path in my database:
C:/xampp/htdocs/Uploadtest/assets/upimages/test.jpg

when i change the path in my db and change it to :
http://localhost/Uploadtest/assets/upimages/test.jpg
it works fine.

my question is. how can i adjust my full_path to come up with the 2nd path. Remember that the location of my upimages is outside of the application folder which i created an asset/upimages

Comment: why you want to save full file path in DB? As you know your directory where images available, you may save only file name then use `echo base_url('assets/upimages').'/'.$file_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your file path as like as following:

```
$image_url = base_url().'assets/upimages/'.$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
$imagedb = $this->prof_model->user_img($image_url,$userid);
```

Comment: sir here is its output. [::1]/UploadTest/assets/upimages/.. Why instead of localhost why "[:::1]"

Comment: you didn't set the `base_url` in your config.php. here is some information about it: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/codeigniter/3643/base-url-in-codeigniter#t=201610060343287203569      also installation : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/codeigniter/929/installation-and-setup

Comment: thaks sir i got it already i change it with . 
base_url().'assets/upimages/'.$data['upload_data']['file_name'].$data['file_name'];